# FPDF2 Python TypeError

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf2

Error Python FPDF. Drawing a table

```py
with pdf.table(
    borders_layout="NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES",
    cell_fill_color=(224, 235, 255),
    cell_fill_logic=lambda i, j: i % 2,
    col_widths=(42, 39, 35, 42),
    headings_style=headings_style,
    line_height=6,
    text_align=("LEFT", "CENTER", "RIGHT", "RIGHT"),
    width=160,
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
```

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cell_fill_logic'`

Comment: https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html   cell_fill_logic=lambda i, j: i % 2, ???!!!!!

Comment: As the error message says, the constructor of the class FPDF.Table does not have a `cell_fill_logic` keyword argument. The only ones like that are  `cell_fill_color` and `cell_fill_mode`. It looks like wherever you are copying this code from either has an error, or is talking about a different version, or maybe you copied it wrong. See for yourself in the docs, here: https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/table.html

Comment: better link https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html#tuto-5-creating-tables

Comment: I have already seen inside their documentation.And it's their own code I have copy and past in my IDE. (https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html).The code is in the Tuto 5

Answer (score 0):

use `cell_fill_mode` instead of `cell_fill_logic` as per comment above https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/table.html#fpdf.table.Table

Comment: well  cell_fill_mode = https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf/fpdf/enums.html#fpdf.enums.TableCellFillMode and here I get lost : class TableCellFillMode(CoerciveEnum): ???  whta the heck is a CoerciveEnum 
???

Comment: see comments below anser by Pravash Panigrahi

Answer (score 0):

OK, new code, with input as `countries.txt`:

```
sssssssssssssssssss,mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm,mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmsss
jjjjjjj,kkkkkkkkkkk,lllllllllllll
hhhhhhhhhhhh,ggggggggggggggggggg,ooooooooooooo
```

my code :

```
import csv
from fpdf import FPDF, fpdf


with open("countries.txt", encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
    data = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=","))
    

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.set_font("helvetica", size=14)

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_draw_color(255, 0, 0)
pdf.set_line_width(0.3)

with pdf.table(
    # borders_layout="NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES",
    cell_fill_color=(255, 235, 0),
    
    
    # cell_fill_mode= 'ALL',
    cell_fill_mode= 'NONE',
    
    first_row_as_headings = False,
    
    col_widths=(42, 39, 35, 42),
    line_height=6,
    text_align=("LEFT", "CENTER", "RIGHT", "RIGHT"),
    width=160,
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
            
        for i, _data in enumerate(data_row):
            _color = (224, 235, 255) if i % 2 == 0 else None
            
        #     row.cell(_data, fill=_color)   ###  ----> TypeError: cell() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'

            row.cell(_data, style = fpdf.FontFace(fill_color = _color))

pdf.output("tuto5.pdf")
```

output with `cell_fill_mode= 'NONE',`:

[image: image from pdf]

output with `cell_fill_mode= 'ALL',`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It's not 'cell_fill_logic' but "first_row_as_headings" .Because ' lambda i, j: i % 2' returns a boolean . And cell_fill_mode in the documentation is not boolean.When I try with 'first_row_as_headings' , there is no error. And the value of the parameter 'cell_fill_mode' is not NONE but 'ROWS' . If you try with these modifications you can get their result (https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/raw/master/tutorial/tuto5.pdf).I think there is an error in the documentation of FPDF at Tutorial 5 where I found the script (https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html#tuto-5-creating-tables)
I hope they will correct their error.
But I thank all of you for your suggestions.